# thrift communication error not catch by promise reject or cath

Tags: java, thrift

I communicate to a server using thrift 0.14 generated code. When a client method calls fails by net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID or net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT, I don't capute any error neither reject function nor promise .catch.

```
  this.sessionClient.LogIn(logInCredentials)
      .then((response) => {
          console.log(response);
          if (response.Result === WSRETCODE.OK){
            this.sessionToken = response.SessionToken;
          } else if (response.Result === WSRETCODE.ERR_LOGIN_FAILED){
            throw new Error('wrong username or password');
          } else {
            this.handle_error(response.Result);
          }
      }, reason => {
        this.handle_error(reason);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
      console.log('error:', error.message);
      this.privateErrorEvent.emit( error.message);
    });
```

Comment: Thrift 14? You mean development master (0.14.0)?

Comment: Corrected version number